# Tool to spider site and look for 400 or 500 errors?

Tags: http, web-crawler

I just converted a huge .Net Website Project to a .Net Web App project.
It now builds.

However deep in the site we are finding run-time 500 errors.
Unfortunately it takes forever to find these.

Are there any tools that can spider a whole site and list out an 500 errors?

I saw the IIS 7 SEO Optimization toolkit - it has a spider, however I do not think it will work for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your site is already in production, you better to use the log file to trace these messages,

You can find more detail in this post

[How can I trace IIS 500 errors thrown by my webservice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/557490/how-can-i-trace-iis-500-errors-thrown-by-my-webservice)